# Why all memory (RAM) gets used by the SQL Server service

Tags: sql-server, memory, ram, database-administration

I have my first issue related to DBA responsibilities. 
Full backups occur on Friday night and run through Saturday.   I start receiving high memory usage alerts by Sunday evening, so I have to restart the production server almost every night. Otherwise, all memory (RAM) gets used by SQL Server.
I’m curious as to what is causing the SQL Server to use up all RAM.  My guess is that it’s related to some sort of synchronization to Test database on that same server , but I didn’t see any sign of that.

This is the only SQL server that I’ve had to restart daily, otherwise the entire server behaves sluggishly the next day.  I would expect the SQL server to reach its max memory usage during peak hours, no?  To me, it seems odd that max memory is used either at the end of the day or early the next morning, following periods of relative non-activity on that server (aside from backup jobs).  So, naturally, my guess is that there must be some process that is causing this event at those odd times.

What would be the first things to do in order to find the cause of it?

Comment: Databases are supposed to use up a lot of memory-- it helps them get faster. Now, when you're running backups, lots of locks and things happen that create more memory/disk space usage...If you've got LONG running sessions, they could indicate an issue. What's your longest running session when it starts to be overloaded?

Comment: First off, a sanity check...  How much physical RAM is on the server?  How much physical RAM do you intend to reserve for other processes (including other SQL Server instances) on the server?  How much RAM have you told SQL Server it can use?  Have you possibly over-allocated RAM on the server?

Comment: Where are the high memory alerts from - the windows event viewer or the SQL Logs? What's the actual message? How much RAM is installed on the server and how much is SQL Server configured to use? (check as per here: https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/18/t/1693). Is this a physical box, a VM or a cloud machine? Does this server only run SQL Server? If it is then _generally_ you set SQL MAX RAM to the total RAM minus 2 or 4 Gigabytes.

Comment: Here’s an example of what’s curious.  Server reboots don’t take place on Friday and Saturday nights.  Full backups take place on Friday night and run for a couple of hours.  There is light database usage on Saturdays.  By Sunday afternoon, I am already getting notifications of high memory usage and reboots occur Sunday nights, even during light usage.  During weekdays, I can probably avoid having to reboot for a day and a half, at most, and this is during production usage.  So the reboot cycle is roughly the same whether the server is being used heavily or not.

Comment: That's curious but not much use in answering your question. Performance troubleshooting is complicated, and unless you answer some comments, no one will be able to help. With regards to timing of the issue, you are the only one with access to the system so only you can work it out. If you undertake some investigation on what is running on the server at the time (SQL Agent jobs? Things other than SQL) you might find the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Windows Server so I tried to get an accurate information from other people. 
We have monitoring software that reports on overall server memory.  I get an email when usage gets too high.

The server has 64 GB RAM and SQL has about 58 GB allocated.